# How can I add an image to a question/answer?

Tags: support, faq, images

I'm asking/answering a question and would like to include a picture, how can I add an image to my question/answer?

Comment: Could we put a link to this question/answer in this page where it suggests putting in pictures but provides no help for new people on HOW to do that: http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Ecnerwal Great suggestion! Many people don't post pictures simply because they don't know how. I had studied the markdown editing page but found it confusing, so a kind person in a chat room taught me. Since the page you referenced specifically asks for pictures, that would be the perfect place for a quick sentence directing people to the "image" button. In addition to helping new users, it would minimize the number of comments asking people to add pictures to their question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When creating or editing questions/answers, you'll notice a bunch of strange images above the text field.

[image]

Notice this one:

[image]

When you click it, a dialog will be displayed so you can select the image you'd like to add.

[image]

If the image is on your computer, simply drag and drop and image or click `Browse`. Locate the file you want to add, and click `Add picture`.

To use an image on the internet, use your browser to find the image that you want to add, right click it and choose `Copy Image URL`. Next paste the image URL in the box provided. Then click `Add picture`.

That's it!

For more help editing posts, check out the [Markdown Editing Help](https://diy.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page.

If you're using the Android app, follow the instructions described in [this answer](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/990/33).