# Announcement: new users can now post images

Tags: discussion, images, new-users

Since the beginning of Stack Exchange, new users—those with less than 10 rep—have not been allowed to add images to their posts. Since this can be a deterrent for them, other users on several sites have asked for this restriction to be removed. In September 2013, [Stack Exchange lifted the restriction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/146318), so new users can add photos directly to their posts and in November 2017 [increased the number of links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302390/remove-the-2-link-limit-for-new-users-everywhere) (which includes images) from two to eight.

### What does this mean?

1. If you see a post from a new user that **would benefit from** a photograph, ask them in a comment to add one and direct them to the image control above the editor (or the <kbd>Ctrl-G</kbd> keyboard shortcut for the same). (Previously, you'd have had to ask them to upload it somewhere, post a link and wait for a higher-rep user to edit it into the post).
2. If a question **needs** a photograph, meaning that it doesn't provide enough detail in the text to be answerable, in addition to the comment as above, also vote or flag to close the question. Use a custom close reason to indicate why it's unanswerable.
3. If you see this privilege being abused (users posting spam, etc.), please flag it and the moderators will take care of it as soon as possible.

---

**tl;dr** New users (those with less than 10 rep) can now add images directly to their posts. Where it's appropriate, please help them by leaving comments asking them to do so, and pointing them to the [instructions](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/523/how-can-i-add-an-image-to-a-question-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I've updated [what topics can I ask about here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the help section to remove the suggestion for new users to post a link.