# How do I add pictures to a question from my phone?

Tags: support, images, questions

The title says it all. When I post questions from my phone I don't get the option to add a picture. I think.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to use the appropriate markup, or wait until the feature is implemented.  The mobile app currently does not support adding photos, at least not that I'm aware of.

The markup is:
`![Image description][1]`

`[1]: link to image`

Example:
[Sample image http://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10](http://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10)

---

This functionality has been added to the Android app. When editing a post, you'll notice a camera button below the edit field.

[image: Android app in edit mode]

Click the button, and a dialog will appear asking where you'd like to get the photo from.

[image: Android app select image source]

If you choose `From Device`, you'll be able to select an image that is stored on your phone. If you select `From URL`, you'll have to enter the URL and press `Insert`

[image: Android app insert image from URL]

If using a web browser, follow the instructions  in [this answer](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/524/33)